# HTML and CSS centering

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center a search bar on my webpage. I currently center the bar in the HTML using the following code:

```
<div class="search" > 
   <form action="search" align="center">
  <input type = "text" name= "search" placeholder= "THIS DOESNT WORK..."/>
  <input type = "submit" value ="Search"/><a href="Browse.html" id="browse">Browse</a>
   </form>
</div>
```

However I cannot validate my page whilst the styling is in the HTML.

My issue is that I cannot work out how to center the search bar in the CSS.

I've been looking into it and it is my understanding that this should work:

```
#search{
width:400;
margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

}
```

However this does not work.

I am pretty new to this so sorry if this is very basic.

Comment: It appears to be working in this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kj9AD/

Comment: Seams to work nicely http://jsfiddle.net/TFwp4/ Can you screenshot it

Comment: Evidently we all think the same way :)

Comment: hehe, you need a good eye to find the mistake :P

Comment: Ive added the screen shot, i tried editing the parent width to 100% and it still doesnt work :'(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this code appears to be working in JSFiddle, my suggestion is that you be sure the parent element containing `<div class='search'></div>` is wide enough to accommodate a 400px centered element. Try setting its parent's width to 100% and see if that works.

without parent: http://jsfiddle.net/kj9AD

with parent: http://jsfiddle.net/kj9AD/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
Class -> .
```

This is the difference

```
ID    -> #
```

If you have an element with `class="search"`, in CSS you use `.search{/* style here */}`, but if you have an element with `id="search"`, in CSS you have to use `#search{/* style here */}`

In your code, you have `class="search"`, and in CSS you have `#search{}`

So, this will work:

```
<div class="search" > 
   <form action="search">
  <input type = "text" name= "search" placeholder= "THIS DOESNT WORK..."/>
  <input type = "submit" value ="Search"/><a href="Browse.html" id="browse">Browse</a>
   </form>
</div>
<style>
    .search{
    width:400;
    margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
</style>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp

Answer (score 0):

You should put a width 100% on .search and text align on form

http://jsfiddle.net/UTrSU/

```
.search{
width:100%;
}
form {text-align:center;}
```

When you have a div class you should put ".name" and when is a div id you should put"#name"